# Basic z index not working

Tags: z-index

I'm trying to replicate a simple z index example from a page I've found but it isn't worrking.

The example is on the following page: [Please click here](http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/css_z-index.cfm):

The example shows two divs overlapping. However when I try to replicate the example by creating a basic page using the following code that I copied & pasted from the example page, rather than the divs overlapping as they do on the example page they just stack above the other vertically on the page.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<style type="text/css">
div { border:1px solid black; }
.infront {
background-color:#ff9900;
width:100px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
top: 10;
left:80;
z-index: 2;
}
.behind {
background-color:#eeeeee;
width:100px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
top: -60;
left:35;
z-index: 1;
}
</style>
<div class="infront">
In front
</div>
<div class="behind">
Behind
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example at quackit has errors. But it also uses quirks mode, while your own example has a proper doctype declaration.

Now in quirks mode, errors like omitting the units for lengths are condoned, but not with real (X)HTML.
So what you should do is correct those errors by appending `px` to all the unitless lengths.

```
top: 10px;
left:80px;
```

and so on.